# Is this spam originating from my server?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, headers

I noticed some delivery errors in my Yahoo account, it mentions some of my data/email/servers:

```
h2.adriantnt.com - my dedicated server
176.9.76.194 - ip of above server
adriantnt333@yahoo.com - my yahoo account where I found this message
adriantnt333@gmail.com - my gmail address
```

I cannot tell if this spam is originating from my server `h2.adriantnt.com` or it is just a fake bounce.

It is very strange that I found this in my Yahoo account, from what I remember, I have no associations between this server and my Yahoo email.

**Full message header:**

```
From MAILER-DAEMON@h2.adriantnt.com Fri Jul 31 04:31:05 2015
X-Apparently-To: adriantnt333@yahoo.com; Fri, 31 Jul 2015 04:31:08 +0000
Return-Path: <>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 176.9.76.194
Received-SPF: pass (domain of h2.adriantnt.com designates 176.9.76.194 as permitted sender)
X-YMailISG: Fa14V5UWLDv21cseTePGzalGzxIgcTH1HukLGhxuTrQyeeWm
 ju1btt1E2lyErmhpd0x2HZ_lKW3YyYQ5JyibcS97TtHX49wWdD_sPwp5sDPo
 r25rL_yjngD8z7dKfvFER1Rt4WEf4FmcBLts_hqXI7x45jkIvsr.jADh7G7z
 q_.FktPBgRSXqqsG9QxtnmFVEEHA0jcaFFxRBrse3znAzrtWaeel0s9hR2yl
 RZ.c1oqWkBmNy3xGvfObcb7WSLCPk31LHHhHeuchj8kFv1Dqb7o4ZhuLpIjZ
 QLC9pdGTjd6BO.Um9UvuQL1eRJSjEkq2ROcAu6zWqX4yfUCYLGRgDvYF7S5r
 KeU5MA05pwOmo1zVRr3IzowrLpFofoMRsM9W8yeS8acykToHwJv_a7Bn6_K7
 TsUgym2nP5zFf6Dt0gv5PHBvoPd33hegSLDNfFj.Ptu3B.GKeF0u8sCsK6Jo
 lKKVZcUPCTfmADwpo_GuctJTkhBxb8kL2nB3z.No0005Y0WnSeAVkNFdq7Ua
 M5RGz0HdcpOy4v6A98Nuum.q4Uf2_C5w5YQNqr0ZXeZRRFkdAu49.NZN_zMg
 5LL3D3kmDOKH7VvwJTNR3rzx2fGDqY5kMitThfwR3VKO9casQ5owddaC9vvb
 NMdDR1FuOgO6VY96rO_r5AKkJ9qpoZVJLJJa_JQrlgz.kgH3NBApaNvD7iO6
 7ZbbnGMXoSLgz2yHPfvpo3x1YD6BGA58HksuaqF5tn33BZOslNkG7qknq6TL
 nlw.7r0XmfCSQNn2vdeofVumb7raMRz3PEYlneWARE5hzoPYjUhlDHC7K7LX
 8yZehn9OaN8TCIKhtI8fVynwqta1A2Sz8D4TLejVZCjzwnfJDFqXmWrcQSib
 Nj19tp4z8uhYqhHiIb_aUt4039TItxokLOmUgn9D3h.dq6mGiATOmiMqNoc9
 qdeMJcnj59vaB5C5bCfVzL8m8K55Wq_7Bd2NpXYa_bF4ZqyEyknZ2loSRsnc
 TOgQ3aBI2eVAfG3sydlDC9Unua_7o8Ikl2b.4tlY5pfASVGF6JnEQEh7Xt6U
 j5.MkwloHyptNALCSNPZW2u8UNDZQ52.RC2b63h31q.GkwxDnaLvjimryO48
 Id9SeplxIgKqa6pUW46U6pZfYjtCDK8wCWpHrRc5SSSAgtKCNLmXOO7wqAkD
 uDNSOhzL8WHrBgHWzDKMGudJykfvw2eptdUIKdHwLvcw52hEkTrTlaE.1ApZ
 tkQh6XWl_ZstShuQuY7ba.9U0y1ltECJyVH5xADVSkwofiYsGEy8E2t2GkTP
 AmcXE7c_0d_2AEs8eFJVK8dv8azBQbSHiyveEMAytRXLbsfnEOSDI_TuOR3H
 xSsX10lpS6XhL1.kVkm6yyyl1oFYCff6nbEZ1nBjRoaa7AGbjmXBTbEodxA4
 _4LAsr2JC1v0CbyagpaGbD21nUgekMKn411SigubFxN39V3Y7qkL38Wb4I2y
 0Rk_6lJdiGi.Fgugn0QNZiI.jQm4MW_P53OLy3b83T7UgRw-
X-Originating-IP: [176.9.76.194]
Authentication-Results: mta1443.mail.ne1.yahoo.com  from=h2.adriantnt.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=h2.adriantnt.com; dkim=neutral (no sig)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO h2.adriantnt.com) (176.9.76.194)
  by mta1443.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Fri, 31 Jul 2015 04:31:07 +0000
Received: (qmail 15838 invoked for bounce); 31 Jul 2015 06:31:05 +0200
Date: 31 Jul 2015 06:31:05 +0200
From: MAILER-DAEMON@h2.adriantnt.com
To: adriantnt333@yahoo.com
Subject: failure notice
Content-Length: 5935
```

**Email content** http://pastebin.com/yW4cLJ53

I attached it ^ because it contains Asian characters unsupported by this SuperUser text field

Among others I see

`Received-SPF: pass (domain of facebookmail.com designates 66.220.155.151 as permitted sender)`

That is a valid Facebook IP, is that message initiated from Facebook interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I cannot tell if this spam is originating from my server

The message came from your server `176.9.76.194`. However it is a "bounce" message not spam.

This means that someone tried to send a email with your "from address" to a non-existent "to" address and it bounced.

There are two possibilities:

1. Your server has been hacked, and the original mail came from your server.
2. Someone forged the email with your "from" address.

   Spammers do this all the time and most email headers are easily forged.

   - "From:" address
   - Some "Received:" headers can also be forged.

     [SMTP message spoofing](http://www.shortinfosec.net/2008/06/example-smtp-message-spoofing.html) shows just how easily this can be done using an open (unsecured) relay mail server.

However, your pastebin copy of the full message says:

> Hi. This is the qmail-send program at h2.adriantnt.com.
>   I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
>   This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

The delivery address was `adriantnt333@gmail.com`.

So it looks like your qmail server has been compromised as it is telling you it could not deliver the mail (indicating it tried to send it in the first place).

It could not deliver because gmail thought it was spam:

```
Remote host said: 550-5.7.1 [2a01:4f8:151:10c7::2      12] Our system has detected that this
550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent
550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit
550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. b4si2734370wic.119 - gsmtp
```

---

#### Update

As per conversation in chat mail to `adriantnt.com` is forwarded automatically to gmail.

The most likely explanation is a bounce from a forged email was received by `adriantnt.com`, forwarded to gmail and then rejected as spam by gmail.

This explains the qmail message above.

---

#### What is a bounce message?

> In the Internet's standard email protocol SMTP, a bounce message, also called a Non-Delivery Report/Receipt (NDR), a (failed) Delivery Status Notification (DSN) message, a Non-Delivery Notification (NDN) or simply a bounce, is an automated electronic mail message from a mail system informing the sender of another message about a delivery problem. The original message is said to have bounced.
>
> Errors may occur at multiple places in mail delivery. A sender may sometimes receive a bounce message from their own mail server, reporting that it has been unable to delivery a message, or alternatively from a recipient's mail server reporting that although it had accepted the message, it now finds it undeliverable - when a server accepts a message for delivery, it is also accepting the responsibility to deliver a DSN in the event the delivery fails.
>
> For various reasons, particularly forged spam and email viruses, users may receive erroneous bounce messages sent in response to messages they never actually sent.

Source [Bounce Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message)

---

#### How can I analyze the email headers?

There are many tools to analyze email headers, some of which can show if any of the ip addresses in the chain are on spam blacklists.

These tools can also tell if any of the "Received:" headers in the chain are forged.

---

#### MxToolbox Email Header Analyzer

Feeding your email headers into this tool produces the following output:

[image]

---

#### Further reading

- [Tutorial - Mail Header Analysis for Spoof Protection](http://www.shortinfosec.net/2008/07/mail-header-security-analysis.html)
- [Example - SMTP message spoofing](http://www.shortinfosec.net/2008/06/example-smtp-message-spoofing.html)

Comment: In my initial post you could see `adriantnt333.com`, that was a mistake included by find-and-replace, domain is actually `adriantnt.com`, I hope this didn't caused confusion. Find-and-replace was used to change/protect the actual email addresses.

Comment: @adrianTNT Thanks for the clarification, but it doesn't make any difference to the analysis or answer ;)

Comment: Thanks. I will* mark it. In this message it reached both my yahoo and gmail accounts (exact same user name), do you think this indicates that is more likely a forged message ? 
I want to make sure my server is not compromised. In addition to that, both Yahoo and Gmail fail to deliver valid bounce messages back to this server.

Comment: @adrianTNT The bounce will go to the from address. It looks like a spam run where the spammer forged many from addresses and happened to include two of yours. I cannot be certain your mail server is not compromised ... I don't think so but I don't want to offer any kind of guarantee ... you should check the outbound mail logs from your server ...

Comment: Thanks, I will look up the logs too. Looking closely I see it includes a 3rd of my address, that is adriantnt333@adriantnt.com (same name as at gmail and yahoo).  
Just switched from Qmail to PostFix hours ago, not sure what logs I have left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26585/discussion-between-adriantnt-and-davidpostill).

Comment: I will try to continue this conversation in a "chat", hopefully you have some time. Thank you.